# Xcode Server Gym fails after MacOS High Sierra upgrade

Tags: ios, fastlane, macos-high-sierra, xcode-server

Hi I have a post integration script that calls fastlane.

After upgrading the Xcode Server machine to MacOS High Sierra, I'm getting this

Trigger Issues:

> Assertion: Trigger exited with non-zero status 15.

Other Issues:

> Running task was terminated because it produced no activity for more than 600 seconds (use sudo xcrun xcscontrol --configure-integration-timeout to increase this timeout)

The log for post integration script:

> xcodebuild[52823:3586759]  DTDeviceKit: deviceType from 15c22d0d745a3912fad8946d42495bdafe758771 was NULL
>
> 2017-12-12 13:41:49.174 xcodebuild[52827:3586876]  DTDeviceKit: deviceType from 15c22d0d745a3912fad8946d42495bdafe758771 was NULL

Here's the code in my lane

```
gym(scheme: 'XXTest', 
        export_method: 'development',
        silent: true,
        skip_profile_detection: true,
        export_options: {
          provisioningProfiles: {
            "com.xx.public" => "XXX"
          }
        })
```

Answer (score 1):

Did you ever figure this out? Are you testing on a hardware device?
If so, I have a theory about this problem.

Xcode seems to not include SDKs for very specific dot versions of iOS. I am finding that, in my case for example, I want to run tests on an in-house iPhone SE. That device is running iOS 10.3.2 but trying to run tests gives me the same "deviceType was NULL" problem.

If I look at the installed Simulators, I see that 10.3.1 is included, but not 10.3.2. I believe this reflects the maximum device-testable OS version, though I do not yet have detailed proof of this.

Can you confirm that devices with an OS version that does not match your available Simulator version will fail with this error?

Or, more helpful to me would be if you found a solution?! (fingers crossed)

Comment: hi I'm testing on simulators. Not sure though what is the solution. I have a different error when device doesn't match.

Comment: You do not have any hardware device attached, even devices that you're not testing on? For example, I've seen this error occur just by having my personal device attached for charging purposes.

Comment: Do you use cocoapods to build part of your project, perhaps triggered in a script during one of your Build Phases? I had that, and was able to switch over from a cocoapods installation to just including a static library of the library I needed, and this problem went away.